# subdifferential and superdifferential

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, subgradient

Let $$D^+u(x) = \left\{v \in \mathbb{R}; \limsup_{y\to x}\frac{u(y)-u(x)-v\cdot (y-x)}{|y-x|} \le0\right\}$$ and

$$D^-u(x) = \left\{v \in \mathbb{R}; \liminf_{y\to x}\frac{u(y)-u(x)-v\cdot (y-x)}{|y-x|} \ge0\right\}$$ the superdifferential and the subdifferential of the function $u :O \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous with $O \subset \mathbb{R}$, where
$ u(x) = \begin{cases}
        0 & \text{if } x < 0 \\
        \sqrt{x} & \text{if } x\in [0,1]\\
        1  & \text{if } x > 1
     \end{cases}$

I have to show that :

$$D^+u(0)=\varnothing$$
$$D^-u(0)=[0,\infty)$$

$$D^+u(x) = D^-u(x) = \left\{\frac{1}{2\sqrt(x)}\right\}$$

$$D^+u(1) = [0,1/2]$$
$$D^-u(1)=\varnothing$$

I don't know anything about the superdifferential and subdifferentiel except that it's the set of supergradient and subgradient. Is there a general method to show these 5 questions ?

Comment: You have note defined $u$..

Comment: yep, sorry. I added it.

Comment: Is there a typo in the definition of $u$? It only makes sense if its domain is (a subset of) $\mathbb{R}$, and not $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Yes, i corrected it, thx.